# Hide stdout from a command

Tags: command-line, bash, pipe

I'm running the following command as a non privilaged user: `ethtool eth0 |tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`, which results this output:

```
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted
    yes
```

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get rid of the `Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: Operation not permitted` sentence.

I tried `grep -v` and all sorts of redirection combinations but none of it worked. Also, unfortunately , sudo access for the `ethtool` comamnd is not an option.

Is there a way to hide that line that is added to stdout? Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 2):

## SOLVED:

```
ethtool eth0 |& tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's most probably the [stderr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_(stderr)) that the command is writing to, which has the file descriptor 2 in POSIX. You can redirect it to /dev/null by adding `2>/dev/null`: `ethtool eth0 2>/dev/null |tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`